# How to use ng-if for display table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have two tables (1 and 2) and two buttons A and B.
I want when I click on the button **A** displays me the **dataSource**    and **button B**
and when I click on the **button B** displays me the **maltr** and **button A**

I have already created the 2 tables with Angular Material.

what should i do to find a solution? I can do with *ngIf

file.html:

```
   <button>A</button>
    <button>B</button>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

<br/>

 <table mat-table [dataSource]="maltr" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

file.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Oxygen'}
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA.slice(0, 1);
  maltr = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

Comment: share the code you have tried

Comment: Do you plan on adding more tables? Or just the two?

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 just the two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Danday's answer works too, but I would use just one button. Less html to maintain.

Template:

```html
<table *ngIf="showTable1" class="table2">...</table>

<table *ngIf="!showTable1" class="table1">...</table>

<button (click)="toggleTable()">button {{ showTable1 ? 'A' : 'B' }}</button>
```

Your .ts:

```js
showTable1 = true

toggleTable() {
  this.showTable1 = !this.showTable1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

html:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!showTable1">
  <table class="table2">...</table>
  <button (click)="toggleTable()">button b</button>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="showTable1">
  <table class="table1">...</table>
  <button (click)="toggleTable()">button a</button>
</ng-container>
```

controller .ts:

```js
showTable1 = true

toggleTable() {
  this.showTable1 = !this.showTable1
}
```

note *ngIf removes the table from the DOM which MIGHT cause problems with your code if it cannot find the table it needs. If that happens then do this instead:

html:

```html
<div [class.hidden]="!showTable1">
  <!-- same as before -->
</div>

<div [class.hidden]="showTable1">
  <!-- same as before -->
</div>
```

css:

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'd use "display: none;" in the css.